# Opencart: почему английская версия выдаёт ошибку?

Tags: opencart, opencart2.0

Opencart Version 2.3.0.2 (trs-2.3.0.0).
Модифицированный не мной шаблон. Английская версия была установлена ранее, я ёё просто активировал. После переключения на английский язык, сайт выдаёт ошибки:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in /home/srv113274/darin7.ru/catalog/controller/extension/module/ap_products_listing.php on line 31
Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in /home/srv113274/darin7.ru/catalog/controller/extension/module/ap_products_listing.php on line 290
Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in /home/srv113274/darin7.ru/catalog/controller/extension/module/ap_products_listing.php on line 290
Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in /home/srv113274/darin7.ru/catalog/controller/extension/module/ap_products_listing.php on line 290
Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in /home/srv113274/darin7.ru/catalog/controller/extension/module/ap_products_listing.php on line 290
Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in /home/srv113274/darin7.ru/catalog/controller/extension/module/ap_products_listing.php on line 290
```

Эти строки выглядят так:

```
    line 31:  $data['title']         = $settings['title'][$this->config->get('config_language_id')];
line 290 это строка 'name' => $tab['name'][$this->config->get('config_language_id')], в массиве
$data['product_tabs'][] = 
        [
          'name'                => $tab['name'][$this->config->get('config_language_id')],
          'href'                => $href,
          'products'          => $product_data,
          'banner'            => $banner_data,
          'pagination_data'   => $product_total ? $this->getPagination($product_total, $page, $limit, $tab['product']['type']) : false,
          'btn_more_status'   => $bnt_more_status && $product_total && !($page == ceil($product_total / $limit)),
          'pagination_status' => $pagination_status && $product_total
        ];
```

Поковырявшись в интернете, я заполнил поля в товарах английской версии латиницей (они уже были заполнены, но на русском), но это не помогло.
Что делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. И оказался ap_products_listing.php  тут ни причём

Нужно было всего лишь:

- Заполнить все поля всего сайта на английском в админке.
- Определить все переменные в файлах /catalog/controller
- Прописать переменные в шаблонах /catalog/view/theme/default/template
- Прописать переводы в словарях /catalog/language/en-gb и ru-ru
- Сделать всё тоже самое только в папке с модифицированными футером и шапкой в папке /system/storage/modification/catalog